# Keeping a dialog from showing PySide for testing

Tags: python, qt, unit-testing, pyqt, pyside

I'm writing some test functions for a form I made. There are a couple of QMessageBox that are invoked(one through QMessageBox.question method and one through the QMessageBox.information method. While my custom widget is not shown on screen, these two actually show up on screen.

I tried dismissing them by looping through widgets I get in QApplication.topLevelWidgets() and dismissing the right one, however, it seems my code only continues executing after I manually dismiss the MessageBox.

So my question is two-fold:

1) How do I keep the QMessageBox (or any widget really) from showing on screen during testing.

2) How can I programmatically accept/reject/dismiss this widget.

Comment: A dialog starts a local event loop (if modal, the typical setup), so although there is an accept slot you could call, you can't call it from your main app.

Comment: @mdurant Well... Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a timer to automatically accept the dialog. If the timeout is long, the dialog will still display for a while:

```
w = QtGui.QDialog(None)
t = QtCore.QTimer(None)
t.timeout.connect(w.accept)
t.start(1)
w.exec_()
```

For your specific case, if you don't want to touch the code being testes, you can have the timer run a function to accept all current modal widgets, as you were suggesting:

```
def accept_all():
    for wid in app.topLevelWidgets():
        if wid.__class__ == QtGui.QDialog:   #or QMessageBox, etc:
            wid.accept()

t = QtCore.QTimer(None)
t.timeout.connect(accept_all)
t.start(10)
```

Comment: How do I do that keeping changes only in the test code though?

Comment: I decided to go with mock and mock the QMessageBox calls, as it seems easier to control it like that. Thanks for the help though

Comment: If you think my answer successfully addresses your question, you should accept it. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the mock module instead. It seemed better since the other solution would actually draw on screen, which is not optimal for testing.

If you have the same problem and would like to mock a question QMessageBox you can something like this:

```
@patch.object(path.QMessageBox, "question", return_value=QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes)
```

Would simulate a MessageBox in which the Yes button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense with Qt testing (including PySide/PyQt) to mock your GUI interaction and do dedicated GUI testing separately as necessary.

For mocking GUI interaction, I'd use the [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) library, as I myself do regularly. The drawback of this is that you have to depend on mock definitions, which may drift out of sync with respect to your production application. On the other hand, your tests will be speedier than involving the actual GUI.

For testing the GUI itself, I'd write a separate layer of tests using a GUI testing tool such as [Froglogic Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/). It'll typically lead to more involved/slower tests, but you'll test your application directly, and not merely simulate the GUI layer. My approach in this regard is invest in such a tool if the budget allows, and run these tests as necessary keeping in mind they'll be relatively slow.